# Microsoft Exchange mail features and AD question

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, active-directory, windows-xp, exchange

I wanted to ask is there a feature that allows Microsoft Exchange to download emails through POP3 from another mail provider like Google Apps (Gmail for your own domain), then store it and allowing users to download (POP3/IMAP) emails to Outlook/Live Mail. So I want to Microsoft Exchange to become like middle mail provider.

My another question is regarding Microsoft Server Active Directory, is Windows Server 2008 Active Directory working with Windows XP Professional and is there any new feature added to Win2k8 AD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.servolutions.com/popcon.htm
Above software is installed on the Exchange Server and configured accordingly - it will allow you to download emails from POP and store it in your Exchange Mailboxes.

XP works with Windows 2008 AD - for a feature document, download and go through the following doc : http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/F/1/BF1F01AE-12AA-4274-865C-AD5BF0C5A35F/FY09_CA_WSAD_Handout.pdf

Also, you can look up on technet which has loads of info on all microsoft technologies.